# I can't display an image programatically

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I am trying to load and display a png from my desktop on an IOS ( iPad ) app Im working on. I need to do it programmatically, and not with story board. Here is my code.

```
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myCustomFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"annie.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(14.0, 10.0, 74.0, 46.0);
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(4000, 4000, 4000, 4000);
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

When i run application, ( witht he IOS simulator ) it just gives me a blank white screen. I am new to programming, and I'm sure I am missing something very obvious. But i Don't know what..And i'm not getting any errors, but it just wont show the photo. And I need the photo to be in the form of a UIbutton, because it may need to have touch options.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is almost certainly causing problems.  Get rid of it.

```
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(4000, 4000, 4000, 4000);
```

Instead of setting the image immediately, try setting some text to make sure your button appears.

```
[myButton setTitle:@"I am a button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Finally, try setting the image (not backgroundImage).

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"annie.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This answer is correct.  Primarily, the difference between `setImage:` and `setBackgroundImage:`.

Comment: wow! thank you, being able to do that was about 50% of my program. I can finally go forward. thanks!